# Routing error: No route matches [PATCH] "/users/sign_in" for devise update password

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to verify my update_password api which updates current user password. I'm using devise and my application is SPA, angular on the front end side. I'm currently getting this error when I try to verify the api with postman client.

```
def update
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  if @user.update_with_password(user_params)
    # Sign in the user by passing validation in case their password changed
    sign_in @user, :bypass => true
    redirect_to root_path , notice: "Password was successfully changed"
  else
    # render "edit"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to edit_user_registration_path, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.first.to_s }
    end
    # render "edit"
  end
end
```

[image: Postman Error]

Comment: do `rake routes|grep sign_in` in your terminal inside rails project and post the output.

Comment: Post the output in your question. Comment section is for discussion.

Comment: new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new

user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create

v1_sign_in_page_url_users GET      /users/v1_sign_in_page_url(.:format)   users#v1_sign_in_page_url

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need to specify the user in your headers in Postman. The uri you listed in Postman is to update a user, but your error is saying there's no user sign in path, which I would assume means it doesn't have access to a user to update.